# Proof with Baire category theorem that the set $(0,1)$

Tags: alternative-proof

i am searching for the proof that the interval $(0,1)$ is not countable by using the Baire category theorem.
Does someone know a book or has a reference for the proof ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You refer to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5119.pdf), page $7,$ paragraph after the proof of Theorem $3.2.$

Particularly, the proof goes as follows:

Suppose that $[0,1]$ is countable, and denote 
$$[0,1] =\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty r_n$$
Note that $[0,1]\setminus \{r_n\}$ is open dense set in $[0,1].$
By Baire category Theorem, the intersection 
$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [0,1]\setminus\{r_n\}$ is dense in $[0,1],$ that is,
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [0,1]\setminus\{r_n\}\neq\emptyset.$$ 
However, 
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [0,1]\setminus\{r_n\}=\emptyset,$$
a contradiction.